# Port forwarding to expose home web server

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I would like to setup a personal home server, I bought a mac mini and I installed Ubuntu server on a Virtualbox machine using bridge adapter. All is fine, I can type the ip of the VM in any browser of any pc in my home network and I can see a welcome page served by Apache ("it works!"). So far so good... but now I want to be able to expose my web server to the outside world! I've got a Linksys wag320n router and I configured it to forward http request on port 80 to the ip of the virtual machine. The problem is that if I type my public ip (that one my router assign to me in order to access the internet) in the browser, I see the router login prompt for remote administration. This is very strange since remote login is disabled! (and furthermore it would listen to port 8080 not 80).
I read that some routers may not be able to port-forwarding if you access from inside the home network, but that's not the problem, since I've tried using my iPhone (using my phone carrier under 3G) and now I tried from my office too (which is in another country... so I'm pretty sure that I'm outside my home network! ^_^).
What should I do to reach my goal and solve my problem?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... can someone explain me what I did wrong? :(

Comment: Your question is off topic for Server Fault as it deals with home servers and home networking. It would do much better at our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Though you may wish to search the site first, as this is probably a very common question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you forwarding external port 8080 to port 80 on a local virtualbox. Did you specify port 8080 in the webbrowser by ip-address:8080? It seems you just used port 80 which already belongs to the router itself.

Comment: No, I didn't specified the port, I just typed the ip. I forwarded port 80 to the ip of the VM. Is it mandatory to specify a port different from 80 in order to make my pc accessible from internet? (I'm a newbie when it comes to networking... so, please be gentle in evaluating my questions ;))